# resize and crop image to fit ios device

Tags: php, image

I'm having several images in various different sizes which I'm going to use in an iOS app. However since all images is different sizes it means some are tough for the application to render. Therefore I would like to crop and resize it to fit the iPhone app. The issue is that since the images are completely different sizes it is hard to do this. I want to crop it to something similar to this effect where the image has a specific size, but covers and is centered?

```
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

Comment: is this an iOS native application your a developing? or a web app that you will cater to fit iOS screens?

Comment: it is a native application

Comment: i'm just showing the css since i want to crop it like that way, so it cover and is centered. in ios language this is Aspect Fit